# Batch file rename where part of the old name became directories

Tags: linux, bash, mv

I don't know if this is possible using bash but it would be nice to be able to do this just using bash.

I receive bunch of files (regularly) with the following name pattern:

- `xxx___yyy___abc__def.pdf`
- `xxxa___y_yy___fg-h___ijdfdak.pdf`
- `xx___v-vv___a_fasl-bk___os___23l.pdf`
- etc.

And I need to rename and move them into directories:

- `~/xxx/yyy/abc/def.pdf`
- `~/xxxa/y_yy/fg-h/ijdfdak.pdf`
- `~/xx/v-vv/a_fasl-bk/os/23l.pdf`

Is it possible? Please help.

Comment: What effort did you make on your own?

Comment: Split your problem into smaller parts. First part: how to split a string by a delimiter? Google that and the first hit is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash and this is already your solution.

Comment: I am looking into the answer to that post ... looking promising. Thanks for pointing. I will update this post once I got that working.

Comment: Can't get multi-characters separator work with `IFS`.

Comment: @Pelangi: Do not limit yourself only with the first (accepted) answer. Check other answers too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using parameter expansion.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

for f in *.pdf; do
  last=${f##*_} first=${f%%_*} 
  third=${f%$last*} third="${third%??*}"
  third=${third##*_} second=${f%$third*}
  second=${second%???*} second=${second##*_}
  echo mkdir -p ~/"$first/$second/$third" && \                                                                                                                                               
  echo mv -v "$f" ~/"$first/$second/$third/$last"
done
```

As per update of the OP's question. Should remove all underscores.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for f in *.pdf; do
  new=$(awk -F'[_]+' -vOFS='/' '{$1=$1}1' <<< "$f")
  echo mkdir -p ~/"${new%/*}/" && \
  echo mv -v "$f"  ~/"$new"
done
```

- Remove the `echo` to actually rename the files.

The actual out put without the `echo`

```
copied 'xx___v-vv___a_fasl-bk__os23l.pdf' -> '/home/Pelangi/xx/v-vv/a/fasl-bk/os23l.pdf'
removed 'xx___v-vv___a_fasl-bk__os23l.pdf'
copied 'xxxa___y_yy___fg-h__ijdfdak.pdf' -> '/home/Pelangi/xxxa/y/yy/fg-h/ijdfdak.pdf'
removed 'xxxa___y_yy___fg-h__ijdfdak.pdf'
copied 'xxx___vvv___abk__osl.pdf' -> '/home/Pelangi/xxx/vvv/abk/osl.pdf'
removed 'xxx___vvv___abk__osl.pdf'
copied 'xxx___yyy___abc__def.pdf' -> '/home/Pelangi/xxx/yyy/abc/def.pdf'
removed 'xxx___yyy___abc__def.pdf'
copied 'xxx___yyy___fgh__ijk.pdf' -> '/home/Pelangi/xxx/yyy/fgh/ijk.pdf'
removed 'xxx___yyy___fgh__ijk.pdf'
```

Comment: Does it assume that number of characters per section is 3? If so, my example above is bad. I will updated my question.

Comment: Then post the exact/more example, I'm not assuming anything, I just parsed what was posted...

Comment: I just updated my examples. Thanks.

Comment: @Pelangi so the new answer works for you? or not?

Comment: thank you so much ... very close to exactly what I am after ... the only case that it doesn't is when I have a single underscore in the original file name, like the third case in my example. And that's what happened as well when I tried to use IFS as suggested in another post, it also process a single underscore.

Comment: I think I got it ... changing `new=$(awk -F'[_]+' -vOFS='/' '{$1=$1}1' <<< "$f")` to `new=$(awk -F'___' -vOFS='/' '{$1=$1}1' <<< "$f")` seems to have done it.

Comment: The `'[_]+'` is a regex that will match all `_` without hard coding how much underscores are there.

Answer (score 1):

Make a folder based on two arguments like

```
mkdir -p ~/xxx/yyy/abc
```

move the file inside the folder

```
mv xxx___yyy___abc__def.pdf ~/xxx/yyy/abc/def.pdf
```

Or just make a script accept the file as argument

```
#!/bin/bash
FOLDER="$(echo $1 | tr -s '_' | cut -d "_" -f1)"
SUBFOLDER="$(echo $1 | tr -s '_' | cut -d "_" -f2)"
SUBSUBFOLDER="$(echo $1 | tr -s '_' | cut -d "_" -f3)"
FILE="$(echo $1 | tr -s '_' | cut -d "_" -f4)"
mkdir -p "~/${FOLDER}/${SUBFOLDER}/${SUBSUBFOLDER}"
mv "$1" "~/${FOLDER}/${SUBFOLDER}/${SUBSUBFOLDER}/${FILE}"
```

Usage: ./script.sh xxx___yyy___abc__def.pdf

Not fancy but it works.